# Why isn't atom-beautify working?

Tags: sublimetext3, atom-editor

I'm trying to make the switch from Sublime to Atom. I installed [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) because I'm trying to get the same awesome beautifying functionality as the [BeautifyRuby](https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby) package for ST.

But it doesn't work. So I looked closer at the Language Support section for atom-beautify and found that Ruby requires [Ruby Beautify](https://github.com/erniebrodeur/ruby-beautify) which I installed with `gem install ruby-beautify` but it still doesn't work, as shown below:

Messy ruby code before atom-beautify:

[image]

About to run Atom Beautify:

[image]

After atom-beautify but it still looks bad:

[image]

Going back to sublime to fix the situation, this is after atom-beautify but before BeautifyRuby:

[image]

After BeautifyRuby, notice how the `class`, `def`, and `end` tags are lining up as expected:

[image]

So how would I go about mimicking the BeautifyRuby functionality with atom-beautify?

Thanks :)

Edit:
Console output:

```
Window load time: 421ms
/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/workspace-element.js:26 ::shadow pseudo-element is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.
/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/text-editor-component.js:1010 /deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.
/Users/max/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/universal-analytics/lib/index.js:451 [universal-analytics] Logging enabled
/Users/max/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/universal-analytics/lib/index.js:451 [universal-analytics] Enqueued event ({"ec":"0.29.9","ea":"Beautify","el":"Ruby","v":"1","tid":"UA-52729731-2","cid":"cfa6e44e-d361-4dd1-8aab-3b7bfc384d7c","t":"event"})
/Users/max/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/universal-analytics/lib/index.js:451 [universal-analytics] Sending 1 tracking call(s)
/Users/max/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/universal-analytics/lib/index.js:451 [universal-analytics] 1: {"ec":"0.29.9","ea":"Beautify","el":"Ruby","v":"1","tid":"UA-52729731-2","cid":"cfa6e44e-d361-4dd1-8aab-3b7bfc384d7c","t":"event"}
/Users/max/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/universal-analytics/lib/index.js:451 [universal-analytics] Enqueued event ({"ec":"0.29.9","ea":"Beautify:Manual","el":"Ruby","v":"1","tid":"UA-52729731-2","cid":"cfa6e44e-d361-4dd1-8aab-3b7bfc384d7c","t":"event"})
/Users/max/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/universal-analytics/lib/index.js:451 [universal-analytics] Sending 1 tracking call(s)
/Users/max/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/universal-analytics/lib/index.js:451 [universal-analytics] 1: {"ec":"0.29.9","ea":"Beautify:Manual","el":"Ruby","v":"1","tid":"UA-52729731-2","cid":"cfa6e44e-d361-4dd1-8aab-3b7bfc384d7c","t":"event"}
2/Users/max/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/universal-analytics/lib/index.js:451 [universal-analytics] Finished sending tracking calls
/Users/max/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/universal-analytics/lib/index.js:451 [universal-analytics] Enqueued timing ({"utc":"Beautify","utv":"Ruby","utt":1525,"utl":"0.29.9","v":"1","tid":"UA-52729731-2","cid":"cfa6e44e-d361-4dd1-8aab-3b7bfc384d7c","t":"timing"})
/Users/max/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/universal-analytics/lib/index.js:451 [universal-analytics] Sending 1 tracking call(s)
/Users/max/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/universal-analytics/lib/index.js:451 [universal-analytics] 1: {"utc":"Beautify","utv":"Ruby","utt":1525,"utl":"0.29.9","v":"1","tid":"UA-52729731-2","cid":"cfa6e44e-d361-4dd1-8aab-3b7bfc384d7c","t":"timing"}
/Users/max/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/universal-analytics/lib/index.js:451 [universal-analytics] Finished sending tracking calls
```

Edit 2:
Please see [repo issue](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/1038) and [atom discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/why-isnt-atom-beautify-working/30523) for anyone who is interested :)

Comment: Any errors in the Atom console?

Comment: @idleberg please see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the atom-beautify package is really using ruby-beautify and not rubocop:
[image]
See issue [#1038](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/issues/1038)